# How to Post API in R having header & json body

Tags: r, api

How to call API Post in R

**Request URL**
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment

**Request headers**
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key = some value &
Content-Type = application/json

**Body** application/json

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "language": "string",
      "id": "string",
      "text": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. There's an [R package](https://github.com/philferriere/mscstexta4r) for this API.

Comment: already know mscstexta4r in R @hrbrmstr

Comment: by not using an existing, working API you most certainly are.

Comment: if you know how to call in R then please tell me. I already know mscstexta4r in R @hrbrmstr Im not re inventing the wheel

Comment: https://github.com/philferriere/mscstexta4r/blob/master/R/textaHttr.R#L16-L40 seems to show you how to do this and there are dozens of `httr::POST` examples with JSON content on StackOverflow. You're asking folks to do the work for you.

Comment: `httr::POST('ADDRESS', body = jsonlite::toJSON(listobject))` should do the trick

Comment: @Shape how to create listobject

Comment: just a named list: `list(documents = list(language = "string", id = "string", text = "string"))`

Comment: you'll need to add the headers too, the format should be available in `?httr::POST`

Answer (score 10):

Here is the example -

```
request_body <- data.frame(
language = c("en","en"),
id = c("1","2"),
text = c("This is wasted! I'm angry","This is awesome! Good Job Team! appreciated")
)
```

## Converting the Request body(Dataframe) to Request body(JSON)

```
require(jsonlite)
request_body_json <- toJSON(list(documents = request_body), auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

## Below we are calling API (Adding Request headers using add_headers)

```
require(httr)
result <- POST("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment",
body = request_body_json,
add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="application/json","Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"="my_subscrition_key")))
Output <- content(result)
```

## Show Output

Output