# Having issues posting to rest service in R

Tags: r, rest

I am having an issue trying to do a "put" to a rest service. When I make the call to the service, I do get back a "200" status code, but the values have not changed on the backend.  I can make the same call in Postman with no problem.   I followed the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809117/how-to-post-api-in-r-having-header-json-body) post.  I suspect that my issue is the phrasing of the JSON object - I include some code that does work at the end of the post.  Any thoughts would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
    results1 <- '{ "2341": 
      {"first": 2,"second": "2","third": "0","ot": "0","so": 
       "0","ppg": "","ppo": "","goals": "2","outcome": 
      ["overtimeloss"]}}'

request_body <- data.frame(
  "2341" = c(results1)
)
require(jsonlite)
request_body_json <- toJSON(list(results = request_body), auto_unbox = TRUE)

require(httr)
key <- get_token()
result <- PUT("<redacted>",
               body = request_body_json,
               add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="application/json",'Authorization' = paste("Bearer", key$token, sep = " "))))
Output <- content(result)
```

This postman call works:

[image]

Similarly, this code works.  The main difference here is that I am putting pure html in the "content".

```
content_list <- ""
  if (content !=""){
    content_list <-list(
      "content" = content
    )
  }
  body2 <- c(excerpt_list, content_list)
  website_url <- gsub(" ", "",paste(base_url, "/wp-json/sportspress/v2/events/", post_id)) 
  
  httr::PUT(website_url, body = body2, add_headers('Authorization' = paste("Bearer", key$token, sep = " ")), encode = "json")
```

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you so much for that.  Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem.  And I am not surprised - I've tried to update other nodes that involved non-numeric names and I am hitting the same problem.

I am new to R.  Could the issue be how the string "results1" is phrased?  Or does the json conversion take care of this?  

"{ \"2341\": {\"first\": \"5\",\"second\": \"2\",\"third\": \"0\",\"ot\": \"0\",\"so\": \"0\",\"ppg\": \"\",\"ppo\": \"\",\"goals\": \"2\",\"outcome\": [ \"overtimeloss\"]}}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if I follow all the logic behind JSON modification, but one is for sure -- you are posting a different content than in your Postman session, check the string in `request_body_json` to see the difference.

Building and debugging requests is slightly more convenient with `htrr2`, it allows you to call `req_dry_run()` to simulate requests (oddly enough, it's broken for me at the moment and actually triggers request ..) and setting verbosity level in `req_perform()` is also quite handy. Consider something like this (keep payload as a list, let `httr2` manage serialisation and headers):

```r
library(httr2)
library(jsonlite)
payload <- parse_json('{
                          "2341": {
                              "first": 2,
                              "second": "2",
                              "third": "0",
                              "ot": "0",
                              "so":
                              "0",
                              "ppg": "",
                              "ppo": "",
                              "goals": "2",
                              "outcome":
                              ["overtimeloss"]
                          }
                       }')

# I have netcat at localhost:7777 to monitor requests
# nc -l 7777
request("localhost:7777") |>
  req_auth_bearer_token("token") |>
  req_body_json(list(results = payload)) |>
  req_perform(verbosity = 2)
#> -> POST / HTTP/1.1
#> -> Host: localhost:7777
#> -> User-Agent: httr2/0.2.3 r-curl/5.0.2 libcurl/7.84.0
#> -> Accept: */*
#> -> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
#> -> Authorization: <REDACTED>
#> -> Content-Type: application/json
#> -> Content-Length: 132
#> -> 
#> >> {"results":{"2341":{"first":2,"second":"2","third":"0","ot":"0","so":"0","ppg":"","ppo":"","goals":"2","outcome":["overtimeloss"]}}}
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much.  I completely neglected to check the request_body_json - it was clear that it was incorrected.  With a little tweak of your code to fit my need, I got it working.  Thank you!

req <- request("<redacted>") |>
  req_method("PUT") |>
  req_auth_bearer_token(key$token) |>
  req_body_json(list(results = payload)) |>
  req_perform(verbosity = 2)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, missed the correct method.